# ¿Por qué head es None al revisar contenido de nodo?

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer una función sobre una lista, pero no se me dice que el head es None, cuando intento hacer `nodeend = nodeend.next`

Al ejecutarlo me dice que *nodeEnd* es none y que no puede hace `nodeEnd = nodeEnd.next`, pero eso no tiene sentido porque ya al comienzo del método declaro que es head que es un nodo. No entiendo qué ocurre.

````
def insertList(self,inputList,start,end):
        """La función toma como parámetros un objeto de la clase SList2,
            inputList, y dos números enteros, start y end. La función debe eliminar todos
            los elementos de la lista invocante entre las posiciones start y end, e insertar
            los elementos de la lista inputList en su lugar. Recuerda que asumimos que el
            primer índice o posición de una colección (lista, etc) es siempre 0. La función
            no devuelve nada, simplemente modifica la lista invocante. La función debe
            comprobar que los parámetros start y end son correctos (start>=0, start<=end, end<len(self))"""
        nodePrev = None
        nodeEnd = self._head
        indexPrev = -1
        indexEnd = 0
        while indexEnd != end+1:
            #esta iteracion consigue que nodeprev esté antes del primer nodo que 
            #hay que borrar y que nodo End esté justo en el que está despues del último que hay que borrar,
            #para así poder enlazar la nueva lista
            if indexPrev < start:
                nodePrev = nodeEnd
                nodeEnd = nodeEnd.next
                indexPrev += 1
                indexEnd += 1
            else:
                nodeEnd = nodeEnd.next
        #ahora necesitamos el último nodo de la lista de entrada que buscamos iterando y el primer nodo lo almacena listaAux._head
        listaAux = inputList
        listTail = listaAux._head
        while listTail.next != None:
            #llegamos al último nodo de la lista
            listTail = listTail.next
        #el último paso es enlazar las dos listas
        nodePrev.next = listaAux._head
        listTail.next = nodeEnd           ```
````

Answer (score 0):

ya está solcionado, lo que me faltaba era sumarle al indice del endNode += 1 para que el while no sea infinito, lo que pasaba era que el while iba hasta el infinito hasta un punto que no tenía sentido seguir iterando